# Derive $u$ for an intersection between sphere and a segment of line $P1 + u(P2-P1)$

Tags: analytic-geometry, parametric

If we have a segment defined by points $P1$ and $P2$ and a sphere defined by origin $P3$ and radius $r$. And the segment is part of a line defined by $P1 + u(P2-P1)$. Then if the segment and the sphere intersect, the intersection point lies between $u >= 0$ and $u <=1$. How do we derive the formula for u? The formula below I tried to derive is incorrect.

$$u = \frac{(P3-P1)(P2-P1)}{(P2-P1)(P2-P1)}$$

Do we need to extend the endpoints of the segment distance $r$ along the direction of the line and set the new endpoints in the equation above?

Answer (score 1):

Calling $s_{12}(\lambda) = \lambda p_1 + (1-\lambda) p_2$ and given the sphere as $\|p-p_3\|^2 = r^2$ we have

$$
\|s_{12}(\lambda)-p_3\|^2 = \lambda^2\|p_1\|^2+2\lambda(1-\lambda)p_1\cdot p_2+(1-\lambda)^2\|p_2\|^2 - 2\lambda p_1\cdot p_3-2(1-\lambda)p_2\cdot p_3+\|p_3\|^2= r^2
$$

solving for $\lambda$. If $\ \ 0\le \lambda\le 1$ the segment intersects the sphere.

NOTE

$$
\lambda=\frac{\|p_2\|^2-p_1p_2+p_1p_3-p_2p_3\pm\sqrt{(\|p_2\|^2-p_1p_2+p_1p_3-p_2p_3)^2-\|p_1-p_2\|^2(\|p_3-p_2\|^2-r^2)}}{\|p_1-p_2\|^2}
$$

Attached a plot showing the solution for

$$
\cases{
p_1 = (2,1,1)\\
p_2 = (5,6,4)\\
p_3 = (1,0,0)\\
r=3
}
$$

giving $\lambda = \frac{1}{43} \left(54-\sqrt{379}\right)$ and after substitution into $\lambda p_1+(1-\lambda)p_2$...

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So we get a very long formula for $u$ or as you wrote it $λ$. What is $p_1p_2$ in this case, is it multiplication product or dot product?

Comment: It is a dot product.

Comment: I tested this and the formula for $λ$ does not seem to be correct unfortunately. I checked with formula in this article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93sphere_intersection, and that seems as the correct solution.

Comment: To me the formula works fine. Attached an example. Remember that potentially the intersection can be double so we should check the two outcomes.